# Combine two form input values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

So I have a hidden field on my form which contains a URL (EG - http://www.domain.com?asset=)

What I need to do is on form submit extract the value from a checkbox and append it to the value in my hidden form so that the result will look something like:

http://www.domain.com?asset=123abc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/ -- `.val()` can be used to get/set the value of an input element. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://www.domain.com?asset=',
    jq_checkbox = $('input#my-check-box'), // suppose id of your checkbox is my-check-box
    jq_hidden = $("input#my-hidden-field"), // and id of your hidden field is my-hidden-field
    jq_form = $('form#my-form') // and id of your form is my-form
        .submit(function(){
            jq_hidden.val(url + jq_checkbox.val());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("hiddenfield").val($("hiddenfield").val() + "123abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple call this function on form submir or click event you want you get your desired output here i check output by alert

```
<script>
function check(){

    var checkbox=   $("#checkbox").val();
    var hidden_val= $("#url").val()+checkbox;

        alert(hidden_val);
}
</script>
```

here

checkbox is checkbox ID
url is hideen item ID

hope it will help you